# i echoed a form and ajax code to save that particular form using php but what ever i select it saves only the first row data

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

***This is the page i am working with having issue.The data from the first row of table is getting saved even if i click the save button for below rows.Is there any solution or suggestions for the same.***

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   
   <th>BED</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
   
    <th>RBS<br>Serum Electrolytes<br>RFT</th>
     <th>CBC</th>
     <th>PT,APTT,INR</th>
    <th>LFT</th>
    
    <th>Urine <br>Electrolytes</th>
    <th>Serum & <br>Urine<br> OSMOLALITY</th>
    
    <th>Procalcitonine</th>
    <th>TFT</th>
    <th>LIPID<br>Profile</th>
    <th>Ammonia <br>& Phosphate</th>
    <th>ACTION</th>
  </tr>
 
  
  
  <?php
  
  include'connection.php';
  
  $sql = "SELECT id,fname,mname, lname,uhid,bednumber FROM patientlist WHERE status='active' ORDER BY `bednumber` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    
    
    $id=$row["id"];
    $fname=$row["fname"];
    $mname=$row["mname"];
    $lname=$row["lname"];
    $uhid=$row["uhid"];
    $bednumber=$row["bednumber"];
    
    $spacer='&nbsp;';
    
    $name=$fname.$spacer.$mname.$spacer.$lname;
```

I am experiencing problem with the below segment of code that is dynamically rendered from db into a form.Each row will be a separate form with different id on sumbit button

```
    echo"  
  <tr>
  
 <form>
  <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='$id'>
   <input type='hidden' name='fname' id='fname' value='$fname'>
   <input type='hidden' name='mname' id='mname' value='$mname'>
   <input type='hidden' name='lname' id='lname' value='$lname'>
   <input type='hidden' name='uhid' id='uhid' value='$uhid'>
    <input type='hidden' name='bednumber' id='bednumber' value='$bednumber'>
    
   
   <td>$bednumber</td>
    <td>$name</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='rbs' id='rbs' value='RBS,SE,RFT' checked></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='cbc' id='cbc' value='CBC' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='pt' id='pt' value='PT,APTT,INR' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='lft' id='lft' value='LFT' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='ue' id='ue' value='URINE ELECTROLYTES' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='osmo' id='osmo' value='SERUM & URINE OSMOLALITY' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='procal' id='procal' value='PROCALCITONINE' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='tft' id='tft' value='TFT' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='lipid' id='lipid' value='LIPID PROFILE' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='ammo' id='ammo' value='AMMONIA & PHOSPHATE' ></td>
    <td>
 <input id='$id' type='button' class='btn-submit' value='Save' ><input type='reset'></td>
 </form>
  </tr>
```

This is the ajax code which uses the submit button id to save data.
Both the form and ajax code will come inside an echo of php

```
  <script>
  

  
    $(document).ready(function() {
 
            $('#$id').click(function() {
 
                var id = $('#id').val();
                var fname = $('#fname').val();
                var mname = $('#mname').val();
                var lname = $('#lname').val();
                var uhid = $('#uhid').val();
                var bednumber = $('#bednumber').val();
                
                
                var rbs = $('#rbs').val();
                var cbc = $('#cbc').val();
                var pt = $('#pt').val();
                var lft = $('#lft').val();
                var ue = $('#ue').val();
                var osmo = $('#osmo').val();
                var procal = $('#procal').val();
                var tft = $('#tft').val();
                var lipid = $('#lipid').val();
                var ammo = $('#ammo').val();
                
                
 
                if(id==''||uhid==''||bednumber=='') {
                    alert('Form render error.Demographics return empty.');
                    return false;
                }
 
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'labbookformhandler.php',
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        fname: fname,
                        mname: mname,
                        lname: lname,
                        uhid: uhid,
                        bednumber: bednumber,
                        rbs: rbs,
                        cbc: cbc,
                        pt: pt,
                        lft: lft,
                        ue: ue,
                        osmo: osmo,
                        procal: procal,
                        tft: tft,
                        lipid: lipid,
                        ammo: ammo
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error(xhr);
                    }
                });
                 
            });
 
        });
        
        
    </script> 
  
  
  ";
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
  }
}
```

My goal is to save each row data seperately for that particular save button provided at the end of each row.I tried my maximum.I am not a professional.I am doing it as a hobby.Kindly give me a suggestion so that i can correct it and learn something new.

Comment: Please edit your code down to smallest code segment necessary to reproduce your issue.  We don't need the css and all that jazz.  It's distracting and makes it harder for us to locate where you're experiencing the problem

Comment: You're repeating the ids for each row. An ID should be unique on the page.

Comment: Each row is a separate form and each from submit having a unique id and the same id is echoed in ajax also.Still not working.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's unique inside of the form. It must be unique **on the page**. You'd probably have better luck gettin the form that the button belongs to, and serializing the form data.

Comment: Maybe your buttons are unique but the other fields aren't. So it always selects the first ones. The others are all ignored because - by definition - an ID must be unique so JavaScript will assume that all other elements with the same ID are a mistake.

Comment: So the suggestion is to give each form an id and to serialize each form data based on form id right?

Comment: That would make a lot more sense, yes. And if you use jQuery's serialize() function you can collect the data in 1 line of code instead of 10+

Comment: But ... Give each form the same _class_, not id, and handle the "submit" event using that class as a selector - so it handles each form's submit event rather than a button click. And then within the callback just use `$(this).serialize()` to collect the data for the submitted form

Comment: Sure i wil try that.Thanks for the valuable reply

Answer (score 2):

I changed my code according to your suggestions and it worked like a charm

```
<form id='form-$id' method='POST' action='' >
  <input type='hidden' name='id' id='id' value='$id'>
   <input type='hidden' name='fname' id='fname' value='$fname'>
   <input type='hidden' name='mname' id='mname' value='$mname'>
   <input type='hidden' name='lname' id='lname' value='$lname'>
   <input type='hidden' name='uhid' id='uhid' value='$uhid'>
    <input type='hidden' name='bednumber' id='bednumber' value='$bednumber'>
    
   
   <td>$bednumber</td>
    <td>$name</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='rbs' id='rbs' value='RBS,SE,RFT' checked></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='cbc' id='cbc' value='CBC' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='pt' id='pt' value='PT,APTT,INR' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='lft' id='lft' value='LFT' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='ue' id='ue' value='URINE ELECTROLYTES' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='osmo' id='osmo' value='SERUM & URINE OSMOLALITY' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='procal' id='procal' value='PROCALCITONINE' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='tft' id='tft' value='TFT' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='lipid' id='lipid' value='LIPID PROFILE' ></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='ammo' id='ammo' value='AMMONIA & PHOSPHATE' ></td>
    <td>
 <input id='save-$id' type='button' class='btn-submit' value='Save' ><input type='reset'></td>
 </form>
  </tr>
  
  
  <script>
  $(document).on('click','#save-$id',function(e) {
    var data = $('#form-$id').serialize();
    $.ajax({
         data: data,
         type: 'post',
         url: 'labbookformhandler.php',
         success: function(data){
              alert(data);
         }
    });
});
        
        
    </script>
```

The corrected code is given.If there is any more suggestions please comment

Comment: Good to know that you have solved the problem. Next time consider displaying a form of a  single record for editing. This is just in consideration of performance --- imagine if the number of records to display is 1000 then this page will need a long time to load . But of course if the number of records are less and you want the user to be able to edit all the records on a single page then your design is good.

Comment: Thanks Ken Lee for your suggestion.I wil surely consider that.